# Word choice with regarding to its use and length

Tags: word-choice

Few years back, when I first read the word "color" in a text book, I thought it was an editing error, but after researching on the Internet, I found that "color" is as same as "colour" except the former is shorter than the latter in length. Similarly, I have got used to regard "favor" equivalent to "favour". Now, I have read the third word "loose" in a blog of a prominent blogger, which has got sort of official status, given the popularity of his blog. Given the context where the word "loose" is used, it is actually meant for "waste" or "lose". Now, the word "loose" is longer than "lose", so can somebody offer an explanation for two contrasting logics given above?

Comment: bloggers are the stupidest, least-educated, least-proofread, most inaccurate, most sloppy Culture Group which has emerged these long four thousand years.  When ever you find yourself, in any context, using the words "I saw on a blog...", stop yourself, have a good laugh, and get back to reality.  You might as well say "regarding the spelling I saw on a wiki..."

Comment: you go for it !

Comment: Hi @NonymousNT, could you give an example from the blog please!! There is a bona fide verb "*to loose*"

Answer (score 2):

Favor/Color are American-English [spelling variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_spelling_variants) of favour/colour

The difference between **loose** (antonym to tight) and **lose** (antonym to win) is explained best here: [Ten words you need to stop misspelling](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling)

The reason for a blogger to misspell words can be one or more of the following:

- poor education
- laziness
- lack of spell checkers that can catch that error

Comment: I certainly do not hope that misspelling lose with two o's or spelling loose with one is going to end up changing any rule book. Same goes for the rest of the words in the poster I gave you. If you post a link to the blog entry, we could take a look.

Comment: @NonymousNT You mean *different from*. I'm just joking, but *different from* used to the the only acceptable form in the "US rulebook." So if we can get away from *different from* and allow *different than,* why can't we allow people to change from "lose* to *loose?* Now, I personally am one who has to stop and think about the spelling of *loose*/*lose* almost every time I have to chose between them. But at least I try to go by the rulebook, however we define that.

Comment: That's odd I thought *loose* was the opposite of *virtuous* and *lose* was the opposite of *find*!!  ;)